# How can I simplify this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tag_id] => 3
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [tag_id] => 44
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [tag_id] => 45
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [tag_id] => 47
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [tag_id] => 48
        )

)
```

I'd like it to look something like this so its simpler for me to loop through and insert each value into a database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 44
    [3] => 45
    [4] => 47
    [5] => 48
)
```

Comment: How did you create the Array in the first place? Or is this data that is sent to you, i.e you have no control over?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

PHP 5.3 or higher:

```
$callback = function($value) {
   return $value['tag_id'];
};
$result = array_map($callback, $array);
```

Below 5.3:

```
function collapseTagIds($value) {
  return $value['tag_id'];
}
$result = array_map('collapseTagIds', $array);
```

Comment: Both of your answes came in handy, I was stumped with why this wasn't working when I moved to a live server. Checked back here and you saved me yet again (PHP versions were different), so just wanted to say thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $new_array[$key] = $value['tag_id'];
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have just one index on `$value`.  If you don't want to specify the index name just do it:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $new_array[$key] = reset($value);
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: May I suggest that reset($value) isn't immediately readable and intuitive for a beginner programmer. Sure it works, but the alternative `$value['tag_id']` may be more appropriate here.

Comment: Yes.. you are right. But using it, a beginner will (or should) read the manual or search more about it .. increasing knowledge. Is my point. Thanks..